# Problem with empty row of cycle for..in.. How finish it without error?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
with open("/selenium/IA/Users_role/TC/users.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
     your_list = list(csv_reader)
     for row in your_list:
         print(row[0], row[1])
         u = row[0]
         p = row[1]
         p_test.test_login(u, p)
         time.sleep(5)
     else:
         raise ValueError("ERROR")
```

But when cycle find in file users.csv empty row, cycle finish with error:

```
ERROR [66.487092s]: AD001.PasswordTest.test_login
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\selenium\IA\Users_role\TC\AD001.py", line 43, in setUp
    raise ValueError("ERROR")
ValueError: ERROR
```

The question is, how to solve it, without error? This is important for my test.

Comment: You should verify that `u` and `p` are not null/`None` before sending them off to `test_login`. You should `continue` your `for` loop instead

Comment: uhm, I need do, that program finish normal with message - There are not more rows, but without error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem at your `else` statement. you're rising an exception at the end of the list.

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop
>   terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the
>   condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is
>   terminated by a break statement

[break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)